# MikroOrm self parent relation

Tags: typescript, mikro-orm

Hello I have the following relationship:

[image]

I tried to do this in my entity to represent the parent's relationship:

```
@Entity({ tableName: 'product_instances' })
export class ProductInstance {
  @PrimaryKey()
  public readonly serial_number: string;
  @Property()
  public patrimony_code?: string;
  @Enum()
  public type: ProductTypes;
  @ManyToOne(() => Product, { fieldName: 'product_id' })
  public product: Product;
  @ManyToOne(() => Contract, { fieldName: 'contract_id' })
  public contract: Contract;
  @ManyToOne(() => Employee, { fieldName: 'employee_id' })
  public employee: Employee;
  @OneToMany({
    entity: () => ProductInstance,
    mappedBy: 'parent',
    orphanRemoval: true,
  })
  public parent = new Collection<ProductInstance>(this);
  @Property()
  public created_at = new Date();
  @Property({ onUpdate: () => new Date() })
  public updated_at = new Date();
  @Property()
  public deleted_at?: Date;

  constructor(container: instanceContainer) {
    this.serial_number = container.serial_number;
    this.patrimony_code = container.patrimony_code;
    this.type = ProductTypes[container.type];
    this.employee = container.employee;
    this.contract = container.contract;
    this.product = container.product;
  }

  static build = (container: instanceContainer): ProductInstance => {
    return new ProductInstance(container);
  };
}
```

but for some reason i am getting the following error in my one to many relationship:

> Both ProductInstance.parent and ProductInstance.parent are defined as
> owning sides, use 'mappedBy' on one of them

should i create a one to many relationship and a many to one relationship?

Answer (score 1):

You added an `OneToMany` relationship for the parent relationship.
That means, that you define `parent` a list of parents.

Also, you define `parent` to be also the reverse relationship key.

You should change this:

```
  @OneToMany({
    entity: () => ProductInstance,
    mappedBy: 'parent',
    orphanRemoval: true,
  })
  public parent = new Collection<ProductInstance>(this);
```

To this:

```
  @ManyToOne({
    entity: () => ProductInstance,
    mappedBy: 'children',
  })
  public parent: ProductInstance;

  @OneToMany({
    entity: () => ProductInstance,
    mappedBy: 'parent',
  })
  public children = new Collection<ProductInstance>(this);
```